# AOSP local Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, local, android-source, android.mk

I'm working on an AOSP based distribution. And I'm trying to implement Local Unit Tests (not Instrumented or CTS), just plain local Unit Tests, using frameworks like **jUnit**, **Mockito**, **Powermock**, **Hamcrest** and if necessary **Robolectic**.

Currently, I'm able to build trough `Android.mk` an app like Launcher a simple Unit Test, and run it through CLI (Command Line Interface).
The problem is that when the unit test starts to get more complicated, I have issues with **PowerMockito**:

> error: cannot access MemberModifier
>   import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

Anyway, my intention with this question is to know if anyone has some example of an AOSP project running with local Unit Tests.

Comment: What CLI command did you use?